# how to dual boot windows 7 and xubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

I have been wondering if I can boot windows 7 and xubuntu 12.04 LTS
I have Samsung mini laptop n100s
With 2 GB of ram and 300 GB HDD
Can anyome help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Install Ubuntu after Windows. Please refer the following link for details.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Comment: This is a correct answer but unless you give some explanations I guess this will be deleted!